# "Headers have already been sent", but without "output started at ..."

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I get the `PHP Warning:  session_start(): Session cannot be started after headers have already been sent in ...` error message.

I read many similar questions, but in my case, the above error message doesn't contain the `(output started at /some/file.php:12)` part, and without it, I'm unable to resolve the issue.

How can I get the `output started at ...` part added to the error message?

I use PHP 8.0 with PHP-FPM via NGINX, and the following proof-of-concept WordPress plugin triggers the error:

```
add_action('init', function() {
    session_start();
});
```

There are no other plugins activated, and I'm using the stock Twenty Twenty-Two theme.

Answer (score 0):

Other place already output the data so session_start() caused that error.

Try replace session_start() with this one on that plugin section code.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
     session_start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the issue persists with your code.

Comment: Oh i see. Can you try change session.auto_start off on php.ini ? May it help. Or the error comes from other place not that add_action() function.
The main reason is some output already send to browser before session started.